# MSSQL: given a table's object_id, determine whether it is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reflection, introspection

For a bit of database-sanity checking code, I'd like to determine whether a particular object_id corresponds to an *empty* table.

Is there some way to (for instance) `select count(*) from magic_operator(my_object_id)` or similar?

I'd strongly prefer a pure-sql solution that can run on MS SQL server 2008b.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a rough idea from

```
SELECT SUM(rows)
FROM sys.partitions p 
WHERE index_id < 2 and p.object_id=@my_object_id
```

If you want guaranteed accuracy you would need to construct and execute a dynamic SQL string containing the two part object name. Example below though depending on how you are using this you may prefer to use `sp_executesql` and return the result as an output parameter instead.

```
DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(max) = 
            N'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ' + 
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@my_object_id)) + '.' + 
                   QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@my_object_id)) +
           ') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEmpty'


EXECUTE (@DynSQL)
```

Comment: I would use `sp_executesql` in all cases anyway. Also +1 for two options as well as using `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT(*)`...

Comment: Wow - how does the first solution work?  You're looking at the number of rows in some kind of index - so, I'm guessing rows in any particular filegroup, or so...?  Why would it not be accurate?  It looks simpler that the second, so if it's good enough; that's what I'll use - thanks!

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - It isn't guaranteed to be 100% accurate. It includes effects of uncommitted transactions, [can be manually updated](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2010/01/13/fooling-the-query-optimizer.aspx) and can get out of synch sometimes and need fixing with `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` (not sure exactly when)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about the concatenation, was getting ahead of myself. I still prefer `sp_executesql` for consistency and other reasons - https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! As a detail to others reading this answer; index_id <2 apparently excludes "rows" of nonclustered or LOB objects:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051.aspx ex

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on what do you consider as `Pure sql`
I've come up with the following solution. It is purely written in T-SQL but uses dynamically built query

```
-- Using variables just for better readability.
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000)

-- Get the relevant data
SET @Schema = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(613577224))
SET @Name = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(613577224))
-- Build query taking into consideration the schema and possible poor object naming
SET @Query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @Schema + '.' + @Name + ''
-- execute it.
EXEC(@Query)
```

**EDIT**

The changes consider the possible faulty cases described in the comments.

I've outlined the variables, because this is a convenient approach for me. Cheers.

Comment: Why not just `SET @Query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + OBJECT_NAME(@my_object_id) + ';'`? What does the interim `@Name` variable buy you? Also what if the schema is not `dbo` (or the current user's default schema)? Also useful to include `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` for this case. Finally, what if the table has a poorly chosen name, like `my table` or `my-table`? Useful to enclose references to objects with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: by pure sql I mean self-contained; not requiring some external scripting engine :-) - dynamically generated sql is fine, so long as it's safe.

Comment: @AaronBertrand `@Name` variable means nothing. The point here is to show possibility of query.

Comment: You should use `QUOTENAME` rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself so the code works correctly for object names containing the `]` character.